OpenStreetMap Polygon data accuracy checking
I was wondering whether there is a method or exercise I can do to check the accuracy of building polygons sourced from OpenStreetMap (https://download.geofabrik.de/)?
Of course when I layer the polygons on top of the OpenStreetMap on QGIS they look similar. But I was wondering if it is possible to say check the accuracy of the building polygons with satellite images?
A simple list of different methods or even a brief explanation of any known would be good. I have encountered "Jaccard Index" through my readings but am not sure if that is appropriate in this case.

To check the building outline from OSM against aerial imagery you first have to obtain the building outline from aerial imagery. How do you make sure that this step leads to an accurate polygon in the first place?
